# Displaying ng-attributes in rails haml partials returned via jquery ajax through $q

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript, haml, angularjs

So I am writing an Angular Frontend for a pre-existing Rails Application. I understand that using $q is at best an intermediate step before converting the back end to serve a REST Api directly to ngResource through JSON, but unfortunately for the time being there is too much logic residing in various Ruby locations to easily rewrite everything into a purely Angular format.

The question is, how do I correctly instantiate and handle ng attributes in the returned partials. The below is a sanitized version of the code.

```
 Company.Controller.TypeAccordionController = (scope, http, element, q, typeJQueryService) ->

   scope.validateForm = (event) ->
     console.log "we are here"

   scope.getTheDamnType = (id) ->
     typeJQueryService.multipart(id).then (response)->
       angular.element('.datePicker').datepicker()


  Company.Controller.TypeAccordionController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$element', '$q','typeJQuery']
```

The returned HAML is being correctly displayed on the page and the datepicker is being instantiated successfully. The first line of the returned HAML is:

```
 = form_for @type, :html=>{:class=>'form-horizontal type-form', :"ng-submit"=>"validateForm($event);"} do |f|
```

Interesting Sidenote: Putting ng-attributes on raw DOM elements within the HAML works like a charm. Example:

```
  = form_for @type, :html=>{:class=>'form-horizontal type-form', :"ng-controller"=>"someFormController"} do |f|
```

The above WILL NOT WORK. The below works like a charm however:

```
  = form_for @type, :html=>{:class=>'form-horizontal type-form', :"ng-controller"=>"someFormController"} do |f|
      %div(ng-controller=someFormController)
```

The service doing the displaying works as follows:

```
 Company.MyModule.factory 'TypeJQuery', ($q, $rootScope) ->
   multipart: (element) ->
     deferred = $q.defer()
     $.get "..." + element, (data) ->
       $rootScope.$apply ->
         deferred.resolve data
     deferred.promise
```

However, nothing happens on submit, the log doesn't print. An alternative attempt was:

```
   scope.validateForm = (event) ->
     console.log "we are here"

   scope.getTheDamnType = (id) ->
     typeJQueryService.multipart(id).then (response)->
       angular.element('.datePicker').datepicker()
       angular.element('form').attr("ng-submit", "validateForm($(this).attr('id'))")
```

Similiarly nothing useful happened.

Any suggestions on how I can get this fixed? On a side note: later in the returned partial there is another element with an ng-controller on it. Needless to say useful things do not happen to it.

EDIT: The HAML isn't actually being returned raw, rather it is routed through the following js.erb:

```
 $('div.form_<%= @artifact.id %>').replaceWith("<%=j render 'form' %>");
```

Which then returns the form partial.

Comment: I know it's not really helpful but it doesn't look like a good fit for AngularJS, if you need to manipulate DOM in the controllers you will not benefit a lot from using Angular anyway. If you continue with angular: you don't need to use jQuery ajax, hou can use $http service

Comment: I am aware of this and this is the long term goal, this is supposed to be a sort intermediary baby step, so that we don't have to rewrite our entire preexisting rails app in one go.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to see the rest of the HTML you're outputting, but right off I can tell you it looks like you're doing your validation wrong.

Validation in Angular is generally done by directives. If a form is $invalid it will never hit ng-submit, Therefor your validation function is never called. ng-submit should be for whatever function you want called *if* your form is valid.

Have a look at this for a demonstration of form validation in Angular:

http://plnkr.co/edit/B3joUY

If you need some custom validation, that's doable too, it just requires a custom validation directive. But that's a whole separate question.

Comment: Thank you for leading me down a fairly intriguing google path with your explanation of ng-submit and how Angular does Form Validation (ngModule for the win).

Comment: I've found a solution. I'ma give you the bounty as I've learned some rather interesting things as a result of your post.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting note I've discovered: Setting ng-attributes on rails functions in the template (haml, erb, whatever) DOES NOT seem to work, while setting it directly on a DOM element within that partial works a treat. Example:

```
 = form_for @type, :html=>{:class=>'form-horizontal type-form', :"ng-controller"=>"someFormController"} do |f|
```

The above will not work, it will fail silently and DOM inspection will appear to show the controller on the form element, it will just not be functional. The below however:

```
 = form_for @type, :html=>{:class=>'form-horizontal type-form'} do |f|
       %div(ng-controller=someFormController)
```

Anybody know why that is/how to get around this limitation and put ng attributes directly on the rails function?

Comment: Honestly, since I've started using Angular, I only ever use HTML files. The only thing my server writes out anymore is straight JSON. I don't need it to render my HTML anymore, I let Angular take care of that on the client.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's a long term strategy. Unfortunately there is a fairly large amount of preexsiting code that needs to be migrated over in baby steps due to deadlines, feature creep, et al

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows:

```
     typeJQueryService.multipart(id).then (response)->
          scope.form = compile(response.substring(response.indexOf("<form"), response.lastIndexOf("</form>")))(scope)
          angular.element("div.form_" + id).parent().html compile(scope.form)(scope)
```

Obviously inject $compile into the controller as compile first.

Then, rather then returning jQuery, return the HAML directly.